# How can I save the input for multiple textbox dialog in Python?

Tags: python, ironpython

I am trying to build a dialog window in ironpython that offers multiple textbox for user input for a table with multiple columns. However, I am having difficulty to pass the user input values to another function. My code looks like following:

```
self.newVal = []
for column in columns:
            self.label = Label()
            self.label.Text = col
            self.label.Location = Point(10, offset)
            self.cb = Textbox()
            self.cb.Text = "Type in new value"
            self.cb.Location = Point(150,offset)
            self.cb.Height = 20
            self.cb.Width = 295
            self.cb.Enabled = True
            self.Controls.Add(self.label)
            self.Controls.Add(self.cb)
            self.newVal.append(self.cb.Text)
            offset = offset + 30
```

The problem is that the self.newVal passed from this code is just the original message of "Type in new value", it does not really take the user input values in the text box, when called by another function. Actually, if refer to `self.cb.Text` from another function, the value is what the user has newly typed.  But this won't work for me because `self.cb.Text` only gives the input for the last column. While `self.newVal` contains all column values, except it is not updated with the user input as mentioned.

Another related question. I attempted to get around with this issue by defining multiple Textbox and pass them out individually. But I can't find a way of using a variable after `self.` . For example, in the above code, if I use
`self.col` instead of `self.cb`, the code doesn't really treat `col` as a variable here, all I get is a single `self.col` with `col` being a string, exactly the same as using `self.cb`. Is it possible to use a variable after `self.` in a class?

Comment: if you can get text from `self.cb.Text` in "another function" then get this text  in "another function" and append to `self.newVal`. Program will not append this automatically, you have to append manually.

Comment: `self.col` is variable because you can always change its values. It is unclear what you expect. Maybe your problem is because you assign all `Textbox()` to one variable so you overwrite previous values and you have no access to previous `Textbox()` - keep them on list `self.all_cb.append(self.cb)` and then you have access `self.all_cb[0].Text`, `self.all_cb[1].Text`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you furas! Using `self.all_cb.append(self.cb)` instead of `self.newVal.append(self.cb.Text)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As furas mentioned, you will need to add each initialized TextBox to a list, or create a new variable for each TextBox. For example:

```
self.textbox_list = []
for _ in columns:
    textbox = TextBox()
    self.textbox_list.append(textbox)
```

Though I would prefer to reference a **dictionary**, where the keys are the columns:

```
self.textbox_dict = {}
for i in range(columns):
    textbox = TextBox()

    # Here you can manipulate the textbox

    self.textbox_dict[i] = textbox

# Then reference each TextBox by column number
val = self.textbox_dict[0].Text
```

You could also create a class function to initialize the table. Here I also show an example of how to create the TextBox object variable names dynamically using setattr.

```
class MyClass:
    columns = 8
    self.init_table(columns)

    # Then you can reference the textbox by variable name
    val = self.textbox_0.Text

    def init_table(self, cols):
        for i in range(cols):
           setattr(self, "textbox_{}".format(i), TextBox())
```